# What does an arrow pointing downward mean in the Git tool of IntelliJ?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, git-log

I am not sure if this is a suitable question for Stack Overflow, but I am just trying to understand the meaning of the downward arrow. In IntelliJ, when I click the Git icon to view the Git history, I saw this brownish part, with an arrow pointing downward. What does it tell me?

[image: screenshot from IntelliJ]

Comment: Means branch is not visible here and is continued below. Same arrow up will be at the other end indicating that branch has more commits in upper part of tree

Comment: Thanks @Justinas, this is my first time hearing about the "visible" concepts for Git. This is very helpful!

Comment: It's not from git. It's how your IDE is showing overlapping branches. E.g. Source Tree will show all branches paths in one place, even if there is 10 of them